# Azure Teams bot is not sending welcome message on user added. working fine on webchat

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

My Flow
1- Created Azure bot in python.(focusing on member added activity and send message activity only)
2- Deployed Bot on azure and changed messaging endpoint of bot with my api url where i want these activities responses

3- Added teams in bot channels.

4- Share the bot URL to teams client.

Problem -> If i run this bot in 'Test in Web Chat' its working fine. I mean It is providing me OnMembersAdded activity response automatically.

But if client add this bot to Teams then I am not getting OnMembersAdded activity response automatically. Client has to send his first message. If he sends message then after i get this activity.

On Client Added To Teams-> No response.
Client sends his first message -> Getting OnMembersAdded activity response + OnMessage activity response

This OnMembersAdded Activity should be trigger when member is added not after sending first message.

Also tried with 'on_teams_members_added' activity but its not sending welcome message to Teams at all.

```
 async def on_teams_members_added(  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
    self,
    teams_members_added: [TeamsChannelAccount],
    team_info: TeamInfo,
    turn_context: TurnContext,
):
    for member in teams_members_added:
        if member.id != turn_context.activity.recipient.id:
            await turn_context.send_activity(
                f"Welcome!!"
            )
```

Comment: Hi, can you confirm in which scope are you trying to invoke the method, in personal or teams scope ?

Answer (score 1):

> This OnMembersAdded Activity should be trigger when member is added
> not after sending first message.

The team has a specific activity handler called **"OnTeamsMembersAddedAsync"** and this will support your requirement in MS Teams. I think onMembersAddedAsync works in WebChat, emulator, etc but not in Teams.

**Reference:**

1. [Teams Activity Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/bot-basics?tabs=csharp)
2. [Python TeamsActivityHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/botbuilder-core/botbuilder.core.teams.teamsactivityhandler?view=botbuilder-py-latest#on-teams-members-added-teams-members-added----class--botbuilder-schema-teams--models-py3-teamschannelaccount-----team-info--botbuilder-schema-teams--models-py3-teaminfo--turn-context--botbuilder-core-turn-context-turncontext-)

Comment: Yes i also tried 'OnTeamsMembersAddedAsync' but that is not working.I mean its not sending welcome message at all on Teams. Should i change something in it to make it work for Teams?

Comment: Also added a code for it. Can you please verify that

Comment: @NitinSharma use TeamsActivityHandler, Check this reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65701014/how-to-proactively-send-a-message-to-a-teams-channel

Comment: @NitinSharma if the above answer is helpful you can mark it as an acceptable answer and it will helpful for others in the future.

Comment: @NitinSharma you can also refer to the existing issue reported in Microsoft bot builder https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/issues/1469

Comment: Yes i looked those links but issue still exists. i also deployed a copy of this bot https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/57.teams-conversation-bot but this is also not working. Note that i only want to send welcome message on personal scope when a new user opens my bot first time.

Comment: I am sharing the bot to new user by bot url(got from teams channels in azure portal).User adds this bot in his space first time and nothing happens.

Comment: Share the url is not enough you should add those bot in AppStudio and install as an app.

Comment: But How can a user of different organization will get my bot if i add it to my AppStudio?

Comment: Valid point, probably you need to add other tenant in your AD because these are security concern.

Comment: Basically that's what i need . Anybody can access my bot by using URL.If any user adds bot then first step is to let me know that user is added(member_added_activity).So i can send him welcome message or "invalid user" message.Problem is that this first activity is not triggering(on_team_members_added activity) at all.If i change this to 'on_member_added_activity' then it runs but after when user sends his first message.

Comment: I think your python code or package have some issue because teammember added functionality should work in teams. I have already shared you GitHub reference if those are not working means it related to your code / package issue because those reference is similar to your issue. You can create a support ticket to microsoft or create a new chatbot and re-verify.

Comment: Well i did dpeloy a copy of https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/57.teams-conversation-bot. But on_team_member_added activity is not working for this bot too.